# Warning: mysql_pconnect(): MySQL server has gone away with using cloud database

Tags: mysql, database, warnings

> *Warning: mysql_pconnect(): MySQL server has gone away in D:\xampp-portable\htdocs\project\database\dbconn.php on line 16*

I got this error on the top of the page, but the page shows correctly. How can i solve this problem or just avoid showing the warning on the page? I am using Cleardb created from Windows Azure trial.

> *line 16: $conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn,TRUE) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get this error any time you get back a persistent connection that has since timed out.

Is there a specific reason why you are using `mysql_pconnect` instead of `mysql_connect`?  If not, try using `mysql_connect` instead.

If this is new code, you shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` functions at all as they are inherently unsafe and will soon be deprecated.  [Use PDO instead](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) if possible.