# 'MySQL server has gone away' but after that the site runs correctly

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

On one of my sites, I keep getting the warning:

```
Warning: mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: MySQL server has gone away in /Volumes/xxx.php on line 11
```

But after that all the queries seem to work fine and the site displays correctly. Is it possible that the connection is reestablished after its gone away? Should I worry about the warning?

Any tip on how I should approach this will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: basically duplicate of [Warning: mysql\_pconnect(): MySQL server has gone away with using cloud database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060235/warning-mysql-pconnect-mysql-server-has-gone-away-with-using-cloud-database)